# How to hide custom option price (+$10.00) in magento2.1.7

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options, magento-2.1.7

I am not able to hide the custom price (+$10.00) in Magento 2.1.7. I am using Mageworx Extension for custom option. How can I achieve this, its my client requirement, as I am not able to hide this.

Comment: This will help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241061/magento-2-how-to-hide-price-of-custom-option-in-configurable-product

Comment: I have tried this..but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/958164768b3eea3dcba7427bc82fdd15b836b031/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/AbstractOptions.php#L106-#L117) to see magento add price in custom options when rendering in front end.

So you can create a after plugin for method `afterGetFormatedPrice()` and return an empty string your price will not be displayed.

Example

Di.xml File

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions">
    <plugin name="hide_custom_option_price" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\AbstractOptions"/>
</type>
```

AbstractOptions.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

class AbstractOptions
{
    public function afterGetFormatedPrice(
        $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return '';
    }
}
```