# How to hide price options on Configurable Product?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, magento2.3

I try to hide the price (in the screenshot +4,20€) on my Magento 2.3 but it doesn't work. I want only T2 display and not T2+4,20€.

I read and test a lot of posts too like but not working on my Magento 2.3.

[Magento 2: how to hide ''price' of custom option in configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241061/magento-2-how-to-hide-price-of-custom-option-in-configurable-product)

[Magento 2.2.3 - Remove price from select field on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236276/magento-2-2-3-remove-price-from-select-field-on-product-page)

Can someone help me to do this ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is working. Use below link [https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/07/magento-2-remove-price-from-select-dropdown-on/](https://www.cadence-labs.com/2019/07/magento-2-remove-price-from-select-dropdown-on/) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236276/magento-2-2-3-remove-price-from-select-field-on-product-page/282290#282290

Answer (score 0):

You can able to extend below class where you can update configurable product options as required

`\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData`

function getAttributeOptionsData()

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: you will need to prepare module and override the above class in which you can customise the function and you can change option lable as per your requirement

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? I'm beginner and don't understand how to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

Override following file:

> app\design\frontend\theme_namespace\yourtheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\options\type\select.phtml

Now try with below code:

```
<script>
  require([
          'jquery',
          'domReady!'
      ], function ($) {
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $('select.product-custom-option').change(function(){
              $('option').each(function(){
                      var selectedOption = $(this).text();
                      if (selectedOption.indexOf('+') > -1) {
                          selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('+'));
                          $(this).text(selectedOption);
                      } else if (selectedOption.indexOf('-') > -1) {
                          selectedOption = selectedOption.substring(0, selectedOption.indexOf('-'));
                          $(this).text(selectedOption);
                      }
                  });     
              });     
          });
       });
</script>
```

> php bin/magento c:c

Comment: I try the solution but it doesn't work. You add the script in the select.phtml ?

Comment: Yes, add this in select.phtml, i have tried in my local its working

Comment: It's not working on my local :(